# Rails render template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, view

Is it possible to render different templates based on a condition in the whole app?

I don't want to write in every view smth like

```
if domain =='cool'
  render template 'cool/index'
else
  regular template
end
```

i guess i need to do something in `application controller` for it

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this in your ApplicationController like this. By passing a symbol to the layout method it allows you to dynamically assign a layout to all controllers in the application.

```
class ApplicationController
  layout :special_layout

  private
    def special_layout
      (domain =='cool') ? "cool" : "not_cool"
    end

end
```